# not able to sort an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

i have problem sorting the arrays.i have two problems.
1.Sorting rightArray with the following code is not working.
2.i also have a leftArray whose indexes should be changed comparing to the right Array,when right array is sorted.Is it possible?.

```
NSArray *rightArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[mutArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 11)]], nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [rightArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Output:after i sorted using the above code

```
2012-10-25 19:11:44.571 Converter[3511:207] (
    (
    USD,
    EUR,
    GBP,
    JPY,
    CAD,
    AUD,
    INR,
    CHF,
    CNY,
    KWD,
    SGD
)
)
```

Comment: its an array of strings.

Comment: paste here the input and the out put

Comment: You say, "...sortedArray = [leftArray...".  Obviously, this code will not sort `rightArray`.

Comment: @philip sorry it was actually rightArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *rightArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[mutArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 11)]], nil];
NSArray *sortedArray = [[rightArray lastObject] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArray);
```

Your strings are in an array in your array. Get the only object in `rightArray` and sort it.

edit

For the second question you can use an intermediate data structure

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSArray *keys = [rightArray lastObject]; 
NSArray *objs = [leftArray lastObject]; // presuming they're also an array in an array

for (int i = 0; i < [keys count]; i++) {
    // we'll use the dictionary to set an one-to-one relationship
    [temp setObject:[objs objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[keys objectAtIndex:i]];
}

NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedObjs = [temp objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
[temp release]; // if not using ARC
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander its working.can u help me with second question too?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array =  @[@"USD",@"EUR",@"GBP",@"JPY",@"CAD",@"AUD",@"INR",@"CHF",@"CNY",@"KWD",@"SGD"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSLog(@"SortedArray:%@",sortedArray);
```

it will output:

```
SortedArray:(
    AUD,
    CAD,
    CHF,
    CNY,
    EUR,
    GBP,
    INR,
    JPY,
    KWD,
    SGD,
    USD
)
```

As Alexander answered you are not passing an array of strings.